# Minecraft Finding The Most Effective Direction To Get To A Yaw Value

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Recently I’ve been struck with an issue i’ve spent a couple hours trying to fix with no luck.

I am working on a forge mod for Minecraft where a part of it involves turning the player to a specific yaw and pitch camera angle.

My issue lies with figuring out which direction (adding or subtracting from the yaw) to turn the player on the yaw side to make the most effective path.

Side Note: The reason I cannot just set the yaw value is because i want to make it look smooth, rather than like the player is just snapped to look in that direction.

The reason this is such an issue is because of how the yaw values work, as you turn going from 0 to 180 then after 180 comes -180 which then goes from -180 to 0.

This way of handling the yaw messes up any math equations I try to find the most effective path, and I’m not sure what else to try.

The one other method i could think of is running a for loop testing going both ways (360 both ways) every single tick, which is pretty ineffective and hopefully not required. Although I will use it if it comes down to it.

Example:

- Input | Goal | Output
- 45    | 90   | Right
- -10   | 180  | Left
- -89   | 180  | Left
- 90    | -180 | Right

Comment: Have you tried converting the yaw value to some more convenient format (e.g. add 180, divide by pi, etc.), then computing your equation, then converting it back?

Comment: I also think it's simply a matter of adding 180, doing all your math modulo 360, then subtracting 180.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I had tried something like that before, so here's my attempt at doing this and how it failed.

newYaw = yaw + 180

distance = newYaw - newYawGoal

and then using the distance to check which way is more effective.

The reason this fails is because when the yaw goes from 180 to -180, the new yaw fix goes from 360 to 0 changing my distance example from 90 to -269

Comment: Add that to the question. A comment is no place for code.